# Checked numbers in checkboxes wont display with message in text area

Tags: javascript

I tried a lots of solutions and I haven't been able to display checked numbers with message. For example you enter couple of numbers, and check them and you type a message into text area; output should be entered message and checked numbers. I tried to put different solutions to different parts of code, but nothing seems to work. So please help me. I hope image is visible.

```js
function textCounter(field, field2, maxlimit) {
  var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
  if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    return false;
  } else {
    countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
  }
}

/*___________________________________________*/

var i = 1;

document.addEventListener("click", function createContact() {
  if (document.getElementById("clickSend").value !== '') {
    var check = document.createElement('input');
    check.setAttribute('type', 'checkBox');
    check.setAttribute('id', 'number' + i);
    check.setAttribute('value', document.getElementById("clickSend").value);
    check.setAttribute('contactNumber', 'numbers');

    var labl = document.createElement('label');
    labl.setAttribute('for', 'number' + i);

    labl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("clickSend").value));

    contacts.appendChild(check);
    contacts.appendChild(labl);

    document.getElementById("clickSend").value = '';
    document.getElementById("clickSend").focus();
    i = i + 1;
  }
});

/*______________________________________________*/


function message() {
  var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;
  document.getElementById("poruka").innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="clickSend" autofocus /><br>
<p id="contacts"></p>
<br> Characters remaining: <input disabled maxlength="3" size="3" value="160" id="counter"><br>
<br>
<textarea onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',160);" id="message">
    </textarea>
<br> Sent message:
<p id="poruka"></p>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="message()">Send</button>
```

Comment: I tried your code but am  not at all sure which boxes are for which input. Where do I put the two numbers and what does 'check' them mean? It sounds as though you have a picture which it would be useful to see but it's not in your question, could you add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified message() function a little bit.

```
function message() {
  var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;
  const cbs = document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]");
  const values = [];
  cbs.forEach(inp => {
    if (inp.checked) values.push(inp.value);
  });
  document.getElementById("poruka").innerHTML = msg + " " + JSON.stringify(values);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I edited the function `message` in this way:

1- initialize an empty array

2- select all the checked checkboxes

3- loop through the selected checkboxes and push the value of each one inside the initialised `array`

4- set The innerHTML using template string https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="clickSend" autofocus /><br />
    <p id="contacts"></p>
    <br />
    Characters remaining:
    <input disabled maxlength="3" size="3" value="160" id="counter" /><br />
    <br />
    <textarea
      onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',160);"
      id="message"
    ></textarea>
    <br />
    Sent message:
    <p id="poruka"></p>
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="message()">Send</button>

    <script>
      function textCounter(field, field2, maxlimit) {
        var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
          field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
          return false;
        } else {
          countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
        }
      }

      /*___________________________________________*/

      var i = 1;

      document.addEventListener("click", function createContact() {
        if (document.getElementById("clickSend").value !== "") {
          var check = document.createElement("input");
          check.setAttribute("type", "checkBox");
          check.setAttribute("id", "number" + i);
          check.setAttribute(
            "value",
            document.getElementById("clickSend").value
          );
          check.setAttribute("contactNumber", "numbers");

          var labl = document.createElement("label");
          labl.setAttribute("for", "number" + i);

          labl.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("clickSend").value)
          );

          contacts.appendChild(check);
          contacts.appendChild(labl);

          document.getElementById("clickSend").value = "";
          document.getElementById("clickSend").focus();
          i = i + 1;
        }
      });

      /*______________________________________________*/

      function message() {
        var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;

        var numbers = [];
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(
          "input[type=checkbox]:checked"
        );

        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
          numbers.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById("poruka").innerHTML = `<p>${msg}</p> to: ${numbers}`;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```